# Correspondence between unitary operator and self adjoint extention

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory

Let $A: D(A) \subseteq H \rightarrow H$ be a symmetric and closed operator on a Hilbert space $H$.

Denote by $\mathscr{K}_{\pm}:=\mathrm{ran}(A\pm i)^\perp$ and $n_\pm:=\mathrm{dim}(\mathscr{K}_\pm)$ the deficiency indices.

Two things I try to find out

> 1.) If $n_+=n_-$ then $A$ has a selfadjoint extention $B$. If $U:\mathscr{K}_-\rightarrow \mathscr{K}_+$ is unitary how can I show
> that $(B+i)(B-i)^{-1}\upharpoonright_{\mathscr{K}_-}=U$?

> 2.) How can I show $n_+=n_-$ if and only if $A$ has a self adjoint
> extention?

Regarding 1.) As I know if $A\subseteq B=B^*$ then $C_B:=(B+i)(B-i)^{-1} \in L(H)$ is unitary and $C_B\upharpoonright_{\mathscr{K}_-}: \mathscr{K_-}\rightarrow \mathscr{K_+}$ is a unitary operator.

So 1.) is the converse of the above statement:
"If $A\subseteq B=B^*$  and $U: \mathscr{K_-}\rightarrow \mathscr{K_+}$ is unitary. Do we have $(B+i)(B-i)^{-1} \upharpoonright_{\mathscr{K}_-}=U$?"

What I can provide as a tool maybe is:

If $V:D(V)\subset H\rightarrow H$ is an isometrie, with dense range and closed domain. Then $T:=i(I+V)(I-V)^{-1}$ defines a closed, symmetric operator with domain $D(T):=\mathrm{ran}(I-V)$.

Comment: Concerning the first question, I guess you meant want to show that $(B+iI)(B-iI)^{-1}$ is a unitary operator from $\mathcal{K}_- $ to $\mathcal{K}_+.$

Comment: Sorry, I have mixed up the ranges of $B\pm iI$ with its orthogonal complements. Any unitary operator $U$ from $\mathcal{K}_-$ to $\mathcal{K}_+$ corresponds to a self adjoint extension $B,$ and vice versa. The correspondence is given by the Cayley transform $(B+iI)(B-iI)^{-1}.$ So first you fix a unitary operator $U$ and then you indicate the corresponding self adjoint extension $B.$ Vice versa, having a self adjoint extension $B$ you indicate the corresponding unitary operator $U.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc thank you. I edited the question. I think if $B=B^*$ then $(B+i)(B-i)^{-1}$ is continous on $H$, since then $\mathrm{ran}(B\pm i)=H$. Therefore I think it must be restricted on $\mathscr{K}_-$ to equal to a given unitary $U: \mathscr{K}_- \rightarrow \mathscr{K}_+$.